# how to center anchor tag horizontally css

Tags: css, anchor, center, alignment

I am trying to create a pure html and css facebook icon for a my website. I think I have most of it done reasonably well. However, when I added a link to the HTML, the text "f" in the HTML was no longer centered horizontally within the div.

HTML

```
<div class="facebook" alt="facebook"><a href="#">f</a></div>
```

CSS

```
.facebook {
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; 
    height: 40px; 
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #1f3060;
    background-position: center;
    font-size:22px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    transform:rotate(-360deg);
}

.facebook a {
    color: white;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.facebook:hover {
    background: #3a5998;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(0deg);
    transform:rotate(0deg);
}
```

Here is a link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2Dx8/17/) I created with my problem in it.

(This has my problem without the rest of my website, because I know thats not the problem. I have checked)

If you have any idea on how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: I don't really see why to reinvent the wheel. http://one-div.com/pictos/facebook/

Comment: `margin: auto` will help - http://jsfiddle.net/M2Dx8/7/

Comment: BTW text-align should be in the container and not the anchor element. Still, it is not centered.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté to answer your question, I prefer to use my own wheel. Basically testing my own skill. Which clearly is not fully working yet

Comment: I see, sorry. It's just that there are way too many social media icons out there already. `:P`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take out the padding-right on the `facebook a` element and add a `text-align: center;` to the container `.facebook` should take care of centering the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/M2Dx8/16/

Answer (score 9):

use these properties for `.facebook`

```
display:block;
text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `display: block;` and removing the `padding` from .facebook a. That will make the "f" centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add
**text-align:center;**
to your **.facebook** section in CSS, it must solve your issue.