# Is it possible to horizontally center an inline element without extra markup or styling parent containers?

Tags: html, css, inline, centering

The question is basically already stated in the title, but to clarify: I'm trying to horizontally center an anchor `<a>` in a main content area.

I would like to do this *without*:

- Using fixed widths
- Adding extra markup (an extra parent `div` for example)
- Styling the parent container (so setting the parent to `text-align:center` for example)
- Setting the `<a>` as a full width block (I would like to keep the clickable area a big as the link itself)

So basically I would like to do this just by styling the anchor itself in css, in a dynamic (shrinkwrap) way. I've been trying, but haven't found a way yet, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: And {display: inline-block}

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to center anchor tag horizontally css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299602/how-to-center-anchor-tag-horizontally-css)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4YqXd/)

```
a {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This question was asked years ago and I stumbled on it today. You just saved my day thanks. What I wanted to achieve was center an element without giving it a particular width for responsiveness and this answer was the killer!

Comment: you saved so much time. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I personally try not to change an elements display type if at all possible, especially to something like 'table' for accessibility reasons.

The normal `margin: 0 auto;` trick does not work here unfortunately.

Hope this helps!

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Center Me</a>
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this

```
a{
display:block;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: While your answer is correct in terms of how to centre an element, the question asks how to centre an _inline-block element_. Making it a block level element would defeat the object.